# Beam/footer connection options with very short post (approx 3")

Tags: deck, beam, post

Edit 2022/10/11 @ 15:28 CDT

The question is about how to connect the beam to the footer, given that the height/volume of the post material doesn't allow all the fasteners that I had planned to use with a standard post base and post cap.  The post heights vary a bit, but all are short.

--

Due to a change in design *after the footings were poured* (d'oh! - we're lowering the deck surface level to avoid code-required railings), I now have only 3-4" from my top of my concrete footers to where the bottom edge of the beams should fall.

A 3" 4x4 post, with a post base (Simpson #ABA44Z) and post-to-beam cap  (Simpson #BCS2-2/4Z) seems silly(?) and likely to crack (or be weak) if I put in all the screws for the Strong-Ties.

In my head, I'm thinking of a base with long enough side flanges that I can attach directly to the beam.  Then I could just have the 3-4" post providing the height but have the beam directly connected to the footer.

I'm in the midwest (no hurricanes, and tornadoes aren't really a concern in my city) so I'm not worried about uplift, but I'd still like something approaching code.

Thoughts? Experience? Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you use a 4x4 horizontal instead of vertical?  Lay the 4x4 from footer to footer.

Comment: 2 pieces of 2x (1.5" actual unless they shrunk it again) material laid flat is what springs immediately to mind. Width to suit your beam. footer, or one of each.

Comment: Appreciate the responses, but the real question is how to connect the beam to the footer;  no matter how I get the needed 3-4" height, I can't use the post base and post cap solution - there's not enough wood volume for all the nails (or screws) that I would use with those Simpson connectors.

Comment: Would it be possible to add another 3-4" of concrete to the top of each footer?

Comment: Your question talks about alternatives to the small posts but it seems you are more concerned with the attachment of the beam to the footings. It would be good if you edited your question to be specific about what info you are needing. If it is indeed the hardware you are concerned about then specify what you have (or better yet upload a picture of the hardware) so you can better be assisted here.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle;  that was definitely a poor title.  I've updated it.

Comment: I assume that in order to keep the deck height low, you're going to use joist hangars to attach the joists to the beam, and not set the joists on top of the beam(s)?

Comment: Doesn't Simpson (& others) make tie downs just for this purpose, like the FSA/FJA?  This isn't a lot different than setting a floor beam into a notch in a concrete foundation wall.

Comment: @SteveSh  

The deck will cantilever, so I can't go with a flush beam.    But I think those FJA anchors are just what I need:  I can secure it with the bolt that holds the post base and it will be long enough to connect to the beam.

Comment: You can download the Simpson catalog and browse possible solutions to your heart's content.  Sort of like a candy store for DIYers!